# What is the best introduction for those studying Single Event Upsets in spacecraft?

Tags: electronics, cosmic-radiation

What is the best introduction for those interested in studying [Single Event Effects, Upsets, and Latchups](http://radhome.gsfc.nasa.gov/radhome/see.htm). I'm mainly interested in introductions for Electrical and Computer Engineers and designing spacecraft to mitigate these effects.

Comment: Daniel, welcome to Space Exploration Stack Exchange! You might want to check out our help resources on the toolbar above, since we work a little differently than a forum. Opinion-based questions (like ones asking for the "best") are closed--your question has already gotten two votes to close by other users.